# Design pattern validation in subclass or superclass

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have following structure.

```
DynamoDBDao{

public get(String hashKey,String rangeKey){
 //validation rule
}

}

T1DynamoDBDao extends DynamoDBDao{
public get(String name,String surname){
 // same validation rule
 super.get(name,surname);
}
}
```

Does it make sense to duplicate validation rule in T1DynamoDBDao?

Comment: What about having `get()` be `final` and have a protected member that does the work after the input is validated?

Answer (score 2):

No, not only do you potentially validate the input multiple times, you also violate the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle.

One option is to have a private or protected member that does the actual work after the parameters have been validated:

```
class Base {
    public final Object get( String arg )
    {
        if( !validate( arg ) )
        {
           //throw?
        }

        return get_validated( arg );
    }

    protected Object get_validated( String arg )
    {
        // do work
    }
}

public class Derived extends Base
{
    protected Object get_validated( String arg )
    {
       // do work
       // maybe super.get_validated( arg );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because T1DynamoDBDao is a sublcass of DynamoDBDao, it can access all public methods from the supercalss. Personally, I wouldn't duplicate it.

Comment: I am trying to duplicate get method. To give more user friendly parameter name.

Comment: on a side note, you could make the validation rule into an interface, and everything you want to have that validation rule would simply inherit the interface

Comment: @VivekGoel improve the parameter names in super class. I would focus more on having a proper doc in the API than good names on a specific subclass.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The base class represent a dynamoDB table.  Which have attribute called as hash key and range key.

Drived class can have different name for hash key and range key.  So I didn't find a proper way to document in subclass.

Comment: @VivekGoel there are long discussions about this, you're just starting one new. Make it an interface/abstract class and let the child classes (that should not be used directly) implement only the relevant methods. Also, if you have a kind of inheritance between tables and the key fields are not the same, then I might this this is a bad design.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza keys are same. but they are called as different name.

Comment: @VivekGoel in database terms, if the name of the column is different, then you're not referring to the same column, unless you use a foreign key to the *parent* table that is the primary key of the *child* table, and then why to use a different name? That only leads to confusion, and again, looks like a bad design.